# updateMyvCardTemp in xmppframework

Tags: xmppframework

i try to update myvcard,but always receive a error message ,

《error code="400" type="modify"》  《bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/》《/error》

my code :

```
XMPPvCardTemp *mycard=[self.appdel.xmppHelper getmyvcard];
NSLog(@"nickname:%@",mycard.nickname);
NSLog(@"name:%@",mycard.name);
NSLog(@"location:%@",mycard.location);
NSLog(@"jid:%@",mycard.jid);
NSLog(@"title:%@",mycard.title);
mycard.title=@"lkasjdfl";
mycard.nickname=@"jdjdjdjd";
mycard.jid=[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"test@im.xujialiang.net"];
[self.appdel.xmppHelper updateVCard:mycard];
```

Comment: Have you enabled XMPP logging? What gets sent? Which server are you using?